# Can features be given as input to hidden markov model?

Tags: hidden-markov-models, hmmlearn

I want to train a HMM classifier with features as input. Considering two observation states(o1, o2) and two hidden states(h1, h2), and some initial probability I apply a supervised algorithm and on the basis of the classifier output, calculate the following
Transition prob :
[ P(h1/h1), P( h1/ h2);
P(h2/ h1),P(h2/h2)].
emission prob:
[p(o1/h1), p(o1/h2);
p(o2/h1), p(o2/h2)]
Is this the correct way to calculate the probabilities?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.